# Select div for removal not working

Tags: jquery

I have a div that i would like to remove via jquery, but it's not working.

JQUERY:

```
$("#answerCommentContainer").on("click", ".editComment", function(e){
    //other things
    removecomment = $(this).siblings('.singleComment'); //.singleComment is what should be removed
    removecomment.remove();
});
```

I chose `siblings()` because reading from top to bottom `.singleComment` is first then other stuff then `.editcomment`

HTML:

```
<div id='answerCommentContainer'>
<div class='singleComment'><a href = '/profile.php?p=11'>Jim</a></b> $comment[$a]<input    type='hidden' value='333' name='hiddenComment' class='hiddenComment'/>

 <a href='#' style='color: orange;' class='editComment'><b>Edit</b></a>

<div class='commentBar'>$difference $periods[$j] ago</div></div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the html too ?

Comment: can you post your html structure?

Comment: Your JavaScript code looks ok (you should make `removecomment` local though). So the only reason why it "does not work" is that your HTML is not structured in the way you access it via JS. *Edit:* Please provide the **generated** HTML, not your PHP code.

Comment: @FelixKling so how should i fix it;

Comment: @FelixKling HTML updated

Comment: Is that really the output you get? `<div class='singleComment'>href = '/profile.php?p=11'>Jim</a>` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming i understand your question, do this.

> **user802370 comment** i need to use removecomment later on so id like to keep it as a global variable

Check out the sample and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYdcv/4/)

#### Sample

**html**

```
<div id="answerCommentContainer">
    Container
    <div class="singleComment">
       <div class="editComment">Edit comment 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="singleComment">
       <div class="editComment">Edit comment 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="singleComment">
       <div class="editComment">Edit comment 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".editComment").click(function(e){
  //other things
  var singleComment = $(this).parent()
  singleComment.remove();
});
```

## Update: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYdcv/4/) and sample is updated

Comment: i need to use removecomment later on so id like to keep it as a global variable.

Comment: [That's not how `remove` works](http://api.jquery.com/remove/): *"selector: A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be removed."* `$(this)` is only one element and it has no class `singleComment`.

Comment: @FelixKling are you talking to me or dknaack?

Comment: @user802370: I mean dknaack. Otherwise I would have put `@user802370` in front of my comment ;)

Comment: @dknaack why use children? editComment is UNDER each single comment.  well, technically editComment is inside singleComment but looking from top to bottom .singleComment comes first

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is actually the HTML you have, then the reason your code isn't working is because `.editcomment` and `.singlecomment` are not siblings. `.singlecomment` is the parent of `.editcomment`

You also are missing a closing div tag.